# Django Model using reserve Python keyword for DB columns name

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am developing a Django Restful API  & I am in a situation where my DB coulmn name ( ie lambda conflicting with reserved python keyword), I need to use this in my `model.py` file which has code

```
CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Default'),
    (0, 'Not Default'),
    )

    profileid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    alpha = models.FloatField()
    beta = models.FloatField()
    gamma = models.FloatField()
    lambda = models.FloatField() # <---------- How to use lambda for column name
    is_default = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES)
```

** I want this without renaming the DB column name

Any suggestion how it can be done ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#db-column

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Field.db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#db-column) for the same. As per the documentation, it should work:

```
my_lambda = models.FloatField(db_column='lambda')
```

> The name of the database column to use for this field. If this isn’t given, Django will use the field’s name.
>
> If your database column name is an SQL reserved word, or contains characters that aren’t allowed in Python variable names – notably, the hyphen – that’s OK. Django quotes column and table names behind the scenes.

Comment: You mean Field.lambda ?